# Comparing GPS absolute positioning receiver accuracy?

Tags: gps

I have two different types of GPS modules which are in absolute positioning mode (pseudorange data)

Lets say one of them is attached in microcontroller (such as arduino, rasbpy, etc) and the other one is attached on smartphone

The spec of those modules are same and there's no clock offset of both devices

How can I determine which one has a better accuracy from the other one?

Can anybody give me some explanation for this?

Or give me some research paper?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to truly test accuracy is by finding established control points that are nearby. These control points will have known values (for example; northing, easting and elevation). In the US the NGS (National Geodetic Survey) survey mark data sheets can provide horizontal and vertical control details with these values. The goal would be to occupy and collect GNSS data on each control point and compare it to the established values.

Comment: What if I don't have any criterion points? I just have two devices of absolute positioning GPS modules with no criterion or higher accuracy points or a value that we can assume a right one. Do I still can calculate the accuracy (and also the presicion)?

Comment: In that case you would not be able to test accuracy, only precision. Do you know of anyone in your area with a survey-grade (1cm accuracy) GNSS unit? If so, perhaps they could establish say 10 control points for you to complete your accuracy portion of the test.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much for your answer, I just can test the precision with statistics analisyst